# Ajax return data above form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am wondering how to join up a variable and to tell js where to place the returned data.

I need to change this line  `$("#commentbox").append(data);` to  `$("#comment_'VAR PARENT DATA'").append(data);` .There are a lot of forms on the page and I need the data to return directly above the form it was submitted from where there is a div called `comment_(what ever the loop number is)`. There is a hidden input called parent in the `Form` which has the loop number.

Is there are a better way to do it?

```
$(function () {
    $('.reply').on('submit', function (e) {
        var parent = $('#parent').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/app/reply',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#commentbox").append(data);
                $(".reply")[0].reset();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just do `$("#comment_"+parent).append(data);`

?

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation to append the `parent` value to the ID prefix.

```
$(function () {
    $('.reply').on('submit', function (e) {
        var parent = $('#parent').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/app/reply',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#comment_" + parent).append(data);
                $(".reply")[0].reset();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, you want to have a dynamic selector. For that you could concatenate the "#comment_' string and the variable. Something like that `'#comment_' + VAR_PARENT_DATA`. It is difficult to anticipate what you are trying to achieve without more source code.